# Apache dav modules produce cadaver: Could not access / (not WebDAV-enabled?)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, configuration, webdav

I installed apache then I am able to access the default page from the command line:

```
$ wget http://127.0.1.1
```

Using webmin in web browser:

```
https://localhost:10000/

Servers>Apache WebServer>Global configuration>Configure Apache Modules>
```

Enable the dav modules:

```
Configure Apache Modules
Module    Current state
dav       Enable
dav_fs    Enable
dav_lock  Enable
<Enable Selected Modules>
```

Restarted apache at command line:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Invoke command line dav client:

```
$ cadaver http://127.0.1.1
Could not access / (not WebDAV-enabled?):
405 Method Not Allowed
Connection to `127.0.1.1' closed.
dav:!>
```

What is missing?

Comment: How come you're not using mod_dav?

Comment: I assume that "dav" in "Configure Apache Modules" means mod_dav.

Answer (score 4):

What does Apache's error log say? I find the error log to be very useful in troubleshooting WebDAV errors.

Did you enable WebDAV for any URLs? Example:

```
<Location />
   Dav On
</Location>
```

Did you set up a `DavLockDB`?

Comment: +1 Dav has to be enabled for specific locations